# watch guard not allowing ping or traffic through wireless client

Tags: wireless, firewall, ping, access-point, network-access

[image]

I have setup a little wireless network for some plcs we installed. When we connect directly to the switch or moxa awk 1131, we can ping all ip's 61.1 to 61.6 and also the gateway and get internet connection. When we try to ping from the server where our data collection is we can ping all but the 2 plcs behind the moxa clients. Is there settings in the watchgaurd to configure to allow traffic from behind a wireless client.

Thanks Trent

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your network diagram, you are doing two levels of NAT (you show two private subnets with the Watchguard between them, and all are after the Gateway).

As the server (192.168.44.63) is in what appears to be your trusted network, and the gateway is in what appears to be your external netowrk, the Watchguard will not route private IP address ranges over the internet (your external interface) - see [this Arin web page](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html).

As a firewall is designed to stop malicious traffic, EVERYTHING should be after that.  In your case, malicious traffic can get to the Moxa clients (unless you have ANOTHER firewall on your gateway you haven't specified).

You should move the switch to the same network as your server (192.168.44.0/24), for security, and so you don't have to have extra private subnet routing rules on the Watchguard to get traffic to flow correctly.